# From List of Strings to params string[]

Tags: c#, parameters

I have this method which takes params string[] skip.

```
public static void AssertEqualProperties(this object left, object right, params string[] skip)
{
    Assert.NotNull(right, "Right compare object is null");
    Assert.NotNull(left, "Left compare object is null");

    var skipPropertyList = new List<string>(skip);

    var leftProps = left.GetType().GetProperties();
    var rightProps = right.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var leftProp in leftProps)
    {
        if (ignoredProps.Contains(leftProp.Name)) continue;
        if (skipPropertyList.Contains(leftProp.Name)) continue;

        var rightProp = rightProps.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == leftProp.Name);
        if (rightProp == null) continue;
        var l = leftProp.GetValue(left);
        var r = rightProp.GetValue(right);
        Assert.AreEqual(leftProp.GetValue(left), rightProp.GetValue(right),
            $"Object property mismatch: {leftProp.Name} in object {left.GetType().Name}");
    }
}
```

The idea is those params to be optional and to be skipped in the test.

This is my property :

```
protected virtual List<string> CreateIgnoreProperties { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

I have a method which converts from List of strings to Array of strings:

```
public string[] ConvertStringArrtoParamArr(List<string> CreateIgnoreProperties)
{
    var input = new List<string>();
    foreach (var prop in CreateIgnoreProperties)
    {
        input.Add(prop);
    }
    string[] output = input.ToArray();

    return output;
}
```

I want to specify the CreatedParameter and this list of strings.

```
result.AssertEqualProperties(CreateEntity, nameof(IAuditEntity.CreatedAt), ConvertStringArrtoParamArr(CreateIgnoreProperties));
```

**When I call the method though it says cannot convert from string[] to string.**

Because it is generic I cannot just specify the name of the properties to be ignored, 1 by 1.

Hence I try to use this list logic where I can skip both- the createdAt and the properties in the whole list.

Comment: LINQ provides a `ToArray<T>()` extension method that converts a `List<T>` to an `Array<T>`...

Comment: If you want the user to optionally pass an `IEnumerable<string>`, then declare the parameter `IEnumerable<string> skip = Enumerable.Empty<string>()` instead of `params string[] skip`

Comment: `AssertEqualProperties` is an extension. So the first parameter (`left`) is `result`, the second (`right`) is `CreateEntity` and the third (`skip`) is `nameof(IAuditEntity.CreateAt`). Your arguments are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`AssertEqualProperties` is an extension method, so when you try to call the method:

- `result` is `this object left`
- `CreateEntity` is `object right`
- `nameof(IAuditEntity.CreatedAt)` is the first element of `params string[] skip`

So when you try to pass `ConvertStringArrtoParamArr(CreateIgnoreProperties)` it is a actually the second element of `params string[] skip`, which needs to be a `string` not `string[]`.

Comment: The problem with putting the whole list in a  string is that it will concatenate all the properties in one. It will then not skip them.

Comment: You just gave me an idea. Put that  nameof(IAuditEntity.CreatedAt) in the CreateIgnoreProperties.

Comment: @grozdeto I'm not suggesting that you put them all into a string; you aren't using the method correctly. It seems that you either need to make `AssertEqualProperties` a standard method, or not pass `CreateEntity` as the first argument, although it isn't clear from the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Reworked the comparer:

```
public static void AssertEqualProperties(this object left, object right, params string[] skip)
        {
            Assert.NotNull(right, "Right compare object is null");
            Assert.NotNull(left, "Left compare object is null");

            var skipPropertyList = new List<string>(skip);

            var leftProps = left.GetType().GetProperties();
            var rightProps = right.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (var leftProp in leftProps)
            {
                if (ignoredProps.Contains(leftProp.Name)) continue;
                if (skipPropertyList.Contains(leftProp.Name)) continue;

                var rightProp = rightProps.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == leftProp.Name);
                if (rightProp == null) continue;

                if(leftProp.PropertyType != rightProp.PropertyType ) continue;

                var leftValue = leftProp.GetValue(left);
                var rightValue = rightProp.GetValue(right);
                if (leftProp.PropertyType.Name.ToLower() != "string" && leftValue is IEnumerable leftList && rightValue is IEnumerable rightList)
                {
                    IEnumerator leftEnumerator, rightEnumerator;
                    for (leftEnumerator = leftList.GetEnumerator(), rightEnumerator = rightList.GetEnumerator();
                        leftEnumerator.MoveNext() && rightEnumerator.MoveNext();)
                    {
                        if (leftEnumerator.Current?.GetType().Namespace != null && leftEnumerator.Current.GetType().Namespace.StartsWith("Intent2."))
                        {
                            leftEnumerator.Current.AssertEqualProperties(rightEnumerator.Current, skip);
                        } else 
                            Assert.AreEqual(leftEnumerator.Current, rightEnumerator.Current, $"Object collection property mismatch: {leftProp.Name} in object {left.GetType().Name}");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (leftProp.PropertyType.Namespace != null && leftValue != null &&
                        leftProp.PropertyType.Namespace.StartsWith("Intent2."))
                    {
                        leftValue.AssertEqualProperties(rightValue, skip);
                    }
                    else
                        Assert.AreEqual(leftValue, rightValue,
                            $"Object property mismatch: {leftProp.Name} in object {left.GetType().Name}");
                }
            }
        }
```

I have added the IAuditEntry to a list of string that will be my params:

```
        var ignoreList = new List<string>(CreateIgnoreProperties);
        ignoreList.Add(nameof(IAuditEntity.CreatedAt));
```

Then I call

```
  result.AssertEqualProperties(CreateEntity, ignoreList.ToArray());
```

The comparer had problems when two classes are compared. If they had classes inside and lists it was comparing the references and not the values. Due to different references the objects were not equal.

The other issue was comparing lists. The lists could also hold classes. We had to cover both scenarios.

**Now it works fine.**

**Thank you all for your input.**